# How to check data type in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

Am checking whether value returned by a function is a snapshot in Kotlin as indicated below, however I would like to check for the exception first(ie when it is not a snapshot). I have tried using !=, equal(), but they all compare but can't check datatype. How can I get the else part first?

```
 if (it is Snapshot) {

 } else {

 }
```

Comment: `(!it is Snapshot)`?

Comment: @dan1st I think you would need the `!` outside the parentheses for it to work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can negate the `is` operator with `!is`:

```kotlin
if (it !is Snapshot) {
   // not a Snapshot
} else {

}
```

The doc for this is in the [hard keywords section](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/keyword-reference.html#hard-keywords).